# Why does my knockout view model initialise with a different value?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am writing a basic knockout.js webpage to learn how to use it.  A value in the view model is set to hold a person's favourite sport, other parts of the html react to the selected value.  I have the following ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable('Andy');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('Blowers');

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function () { return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName(); });

    self.setFavourite = function (fav) { self.Favourite(fav); };

    self.Favourite = ko.observable("Football");
};

// Activate knockout.js
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

and the following html:

```
<div>
    <h1>Welcome <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></h1>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtFirstName" data-bind="value: firstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtLastName" data-bind="value: lastName" />
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <ul class="nav nav-btns">
            <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: Favourite() == 'Football' }">
                <a id="btnFootball" data-bind="click: setFavourite('Football')">Football</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: Favourite() == 'Rugby' }">
                <a id="btnRugby" data-bind="click: setFavourite('Rugby')">Rugby</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: Favourite() == 'Cricket' }">
                <a id="btnCricket" data-bind="click: setFavourite('Cricket')">Cricket</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="visible: Favourite()=='Football'">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Football</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>I prefer football</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="visible: Favourite()=='Rugby'">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Rugby</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>I prefer rugby</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="visible: Favourite()=='Cricket'">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Cricket</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>I prefer cricket</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Even though Favourite is set to initialise as Football, when the page launches, Cricket is selected, not Football.  Any ideas as to why and to how to set the default selected value?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jb43sr9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling the function `setFavourite` in your click binding.

So `setFavourite` is actually being called with the argument you have specified in each list item when knockout binds your view model to the view. Because 'setFavourite('Cricket')' is the last one to appear in the view it is also the last function being called which is why cricket is selected.

You have two options here:

**Option 1**

Wrap these function calls in an anonymous function in your click bindings:

```
<ul class="nav nav-btns">
   <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: Favourite() == 'Football' }">
      <a id="btnFootball" data-bind="click: function(){ setFavourite('Football') }">Football</a>
   </li>
   <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: Favourite() == 'Rugby' }">
      <a id="btnRugby" data-bind="click: function(){ setFavourite('Rugby') }">Rugby</a>
   </li>
   <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: Favourite() == 'Cricket' }">
      <a id="btnCricket" data-bind="click: function(){ setFavourite('Cricket')}">Cricket</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jb43sr9/1/) updated with option 1.

or

**Option 2**

Make no changes to your view and return a function from `setFavourite`:

```
   self.setFavourite = function (fav) {
        return function () {
            self.Favourite(fav);
        }
    };
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jb43sr9/2/) updated with option 2.

Comment: Thanks.  Is this calling the function on binding behaviour by design or a consequence of javascript?

Comment: @JonathanTwite this is by design. This allows you to bind functions to click bindings, rather than the result of a function. When you bind a function, knockout passes the context as an argument into the bound function.